# .getJSON .each() Not Parsing JSON Data

Tags: php, jquery, json, getjson

I am querying a PHP page (not on an external site) using $.getJSON which will return a MySQL result set, I have used json_encode() to format the result set to a JSON string.  The problem is I get the data back but when I try to set the values of some hidden fields nothing happens.  I had this working but now it's not.  I must have changed something without realizing it.  Here's the code:

jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('includes/Lookup.php', {locationType:$('#location').val()}, function(data) {

var valA = $('#valA');
var valB = $('#valB');
var valC = $('#valC');

$.each(data, function(index, data) {
     valA.val(data.field_valueA);
     valB.val(data.field_valueB);
     valC.val(data.field_valueC);
 });
});
```

Lookup.php:

```
<?php
$db = new MySqlDB();

if(!$db) {
// Show error if we cannot connect.
echo 'ERROR: Could not connect to the database.';
} else {

if(isset($_GET['locationType'])){

    $locationType = $_GET['locationType'];
    $db->where('id', $locationType);

    $sql = "SELECT field_valueA, field_valueB, field_valueC FROM table";
    $results = $db->query($sql);

    echo json_encode($results);

} else {
    echo 'not set';
}
}
```

This is what I get in Firebug:

```
<??> {"field_valueA":2,"field_valueB":3.12,"field_valueC":12345}
```

I don't know why `<??>` is included.  I am doing this exact call in two different places, on two different tables (neither are working) this is what I am getting from the other call:

```
<??> [{"field_valueA":905,"field_valueB":18.180000305176,"field_valueC":16453}]
```

If anyone has an idea as to what is going on I'd appreciate it.

EDIT:  Now it seems as if ALL my ajax responses throughout my application are being prefixed with `<??>`.  They all worked before and now they are not, I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: "I don't know why is included." What?? Your question is not especially clear.

Comment: I think the OP is asking why `<??>` is in the response sent from the server.

Comment: Ah... I had no idea. I figured that was just meant as the console.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo I guess, it was supposed to be "I don't know why <??> is included".  But the real question is why can't I parse through return string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!  I am embarrassed to say that I had a typo in my code, it's very easy to miss an extra `<?`.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Great that you solved your problem! To mark this problem as solved, your can click the check mark on either this answer, or another answer you think helped you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Redrider.  I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP seems to miss the closing php tag `?>` in the end. Maybe that's why it's acting weird ...

Answer (score 0):

why dont you simply do

```
 valA.val(data.field_valueA);
 valB.val(data.field_valueB);
 valC.val(data.field_valueC);
```

no need to iterate in your case

Comment: You are right, no need to iterate, but it still does not work.  Is my JSON valid?  The examples I provided are different, one with brackets and one without.

Comment: yes the json is correct you can check it for yourself at http://jsonlint.com/